# async/await access previous result and pass it to next operation

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

If my function uses two independent async operations, then an unreachable backend between the first and second operation would result in `a` (stored) and `b` (not stored).

```
try {
  const a = await createA();
  // error: backend not available
  const b = await createB();
}
```

I could use `await Promise.all()`, to wait until all promises are resolved, so either both are stored or none are stored.

```
await Promise.all([createA(), createB()]);
```

But how to solve this situation, if my second async operation depends on the result of the first one.

```
try {
  const a = await createA();
  // error: backend not available
  const b = await createB({ _id: a._id });
}
```

Is there any way to handle this with using async and await and not chained `.then()` statements?

Edit: I expect that `a` and `b` will be created or none of both. Both operations `a` and `b` saves documents via mongoose driver to a mongodb database.

Comment: You want to go ahead with `createB` even when the backend fails in between them?

Comment: I expect that `a` and `b` will be created or none of both.

Comment: You can't do that if `createB` requires `a`. You need to be able to signal to whatever `createA` and `createB` talk to that both need to work or both fail (e.g., a database transaction or similar) or you need to be able to "undo" `a`. In both cases, the "how" is specific to whatever `createA`/`createB` are talking to, we can't help you without knowing more about that.

Comment: "...so either both are stored or none are stored" this is not true. Promise.all() will wait, until all promises will be resolved. But there is no rollback option. If one or more promises rejects, you will stuck in inconsistent state - some are stored, some are not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Both `createA` and `createB` are communicating to a mongoDB (via mongoose), where both operations will create and inserted a document.

Comment: See my answer, you should create seperate utility functions for your db operations and then pipe them into a promise pipe. The output of each operation can be used is input for the next one. In your high order function you handle the catch and throw a server error if you really cant finish the operation.

Comment: Use a transaction

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a `promisePipe` instead using `reduce`. With [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you can use the output of the previous operation as input for the next operation.

For example:

```js
const myPromise = async n => {
    return Promise.resolve(1 * n)
}

const myPromise2 = async n => {
    return Promise.resolve(2 * n)
}

const promiseReduce = async (prevPromise, currPromise) => {
  const prevResult = await prevPromise;
  return currPromise(prevResult).catch(err => {
    throw err // throw a internal error server here
  });
}
    
const promisePipe = (...fns) => {
    return fns.reduce(promiseReduce, Promise.resolve(1))
}

promisePipe(myPromise, myPromise2).then(e => { console.log(e)})
```

Answer (score -1):

if the second function depends upon the first result then you can use the below snippet:

```
try {
     const a = await createA();
       // null and if id is exists than call createB
        if (a && a.id) {
            const b = await createB();
        }
}
```